# Movie about a ghost playing a piano while the protagonist sleeps, then honking the horn of his car

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

I remember watching a movie where the protagonist at his home, hears his piano playing and comes to know that a ghost plays his piano. He gets terrified and runs out of his home to a bar and then drinks a lot. While in the bar, he hears his car honking outside the bar, he comes out to check it and finds the same ghost honking.

Comment: I think I remember a horror movie about a ghost of a boy playing piano that I watched on a plane, but I am not sure about the drinking in the bar scenario... are you sure that's how you remember it? (Welcome to the **SciFi Stack Exchange** by the way! Since you are a new contributor to the Stack Exchange community, I strongly recommend that you visit the [**Help Center**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help).)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Yes. There was a bar scene. It was at his home where he comes to sleep or something but hears the piano playing and then comes to check out whats happening and find out a ghost is playing his piano. Soon after he sees it he runs out of his home o a bar and then thinks about it and drinks a lot. He hears his car honking and comes out to check it and then again he finds out the same ghost honking his car.